# commutative ring to boolean algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

Let X be a set. We know that $(P(X),\triangle, \cap )$ is a commutative ring with the zero-element $ \emptyset $ and the one-element $X$. $P(X)$ is the power set, $\triangle$ the symmetrical difference (as addition) and $\cap$ the intersection (as multiplication).

Now we define scalar multiplication as: $\mathbb{F}_2 \times P(X) \rightarrow P(X)$
$0 \cdot A = \emptyset$
$1 \cdot A = A$
for every $A \in P(X)$

prove that because of the scaler multiplication, $(P(X),\triangle, \cap, \cdot )$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Im pretty much lost on this one. I looked in the script and on the internet for clues on how to solve this, but Im pretty desperate, so Im posting this without any progress. I would appreciate if you could give me any hints on how to get started with this

Comment: Start with an example. E.g. what happens if $X$ has only two elements? Work out the small examples to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Write down the definitions of the concepts in the question, specifically the concept of an algebra over a field. Then use those definitions to write down what it is that you have to prove: it will be a set of equations about formulas built using $\Delta$, $\cap$ and $\cdot$. Then use properties you know to prove those equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the axioms of algebras:

1. You know that $(P(X),\triangle,\cap)$ is a commutative ring;
2. Show that for every $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_2$ and $A\in P(X)$,
   \begin{align*}
   (a+b)\cdot A&=a\cdot A+b\cdot A; \tag{1}\\
   a\cdot(b\cdot A)&=(ab)\cdot A.\tag{2}
   \end{align*}
3. Show that for every $a\in\mathbb{F}_2$ and $A,B\in P(X)$,
   \begin{align*}
   a\cdot(A\triangle B)&=(a\cdot A)\triangle(a\cdot B); \tag{3}\\
   a\cdot(A\cap B)&=(a\cdot A)\cap B=A\cap(a\cdot B). \tag{4}
   \end{align*}

Since there are only two elements in $\mathbb{F}_2$, you simply exhaust all possible cases.